# Django “The view didn't return an HttpResponse object.”

Tags: python, django, view, response

I have a very basic view where I'm saving a form.  For some reason I keep getting a "view didn't return an HttpResponse object" error.  I looked at this common issue here but haven't found a solution that applies to me.  does anyone have any thoughts?  I've included the code below.  Would greatly appreciate help with this simple question!

```
def EarlyAdopterSignup(request):
    f = LandingPageForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        email = f.cleaned_data['email']
        zip = f.cleaned_data['zip']
        adopter = EarlyAdopter(email = email, zip = zip)
        try:
            adopter.save()
            return render_to_response('EarlyAdopterSignup.html')
        except:
            return HttpResponse("There was an error with your submission. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on what A.L is saying it is necessary to handle the case where the form IS NOT valid.

This can be handled quite simply by passing a bound invalid form (`f`) back to your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view

Is an illustration of exactly what you need to do ^

```
def EarlyAdopterSignup(request):
    f = LandingPageForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        email = f.cleaned_data['email']
        zip = f.cleaned_data['zip']
        adopter = EarlyAdopter(email = email, zip = zip)
        try:
            adopter.save()
            return render_to_response('EarlyAdopterSignup.html')
        except:
            return HttpResponse("There was an error with your submission. Please try again.")

   # handle where not valid
   return render(request, 'your_form_template.html', {
    'form': f,  # <- your invalid form instance
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, to begin with, if your form isn't valid, you're not returning anything. You should be reshowing the form with errors displayed.